# ImportError: No module named mime.multipart

Tags: python, email

Good morning,

For testing purposes, I have made a one-line Python program:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
```

When I run it through the interpeter, I get an awful error message:

> from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
>   ImportError: No module named mime.multipart

I am using Python version 2.4.3. I suspect that the email module has changed its packaging structure in the intervening versions, hence the error. Is my suspicion correct? If not, why is the import statement not working?

Thanks in advance,
ktm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Module reorganization.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0364/) The convention is for module names to be lower case, so some got renamed. In this case, the module you're looking for in Python 2.4.3 is `email.MIMEMultipart`.

[Here's the docs from back then, in case the API has changed.](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.2/lib/node588.html#l2h-3893)

Comment: It's `email.mime.multipart` in Python 3x for future visiters.

Answer (score 17):

Call me dumb, but I was getting `ImportError: No module named mime.text` because my script was called `email.py` .... lol (blame on 4 am programming)

Comment: this was the same issue i had

Comment: My bad as well, I quickly thought it was a missing module, note to myself: "don't use common names for a module"

Answer (score 10):

It should now be done like this:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
```

Same goes for other commonly used modules like MIMEText and MIMEBase (use .text and .base respectively).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well,  from the [docs for Python 2.4](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/node588.html), it seems you need:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
```

(Although you might want to use a newer version of Python, if possible).

Comment: in many cases using a new version is not possible. RHEL, CentOS, and SUSE all use old versions of Python. Google still only uses 2.5 internally as well.

Comment: @Rafe: I know, and I did say "if possible". But 2.4 is really quite old now, and if the questioner can use a newer version, it might make their life easier.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to debug the error is:

```
>>> import email
>>> dir(email)
['Charset', 'Encoders', 'Errors', 'FeedParser', 'Generator', 'Header', 'Iterator
s', 'LazyImporter', 'MIMEAudio', 'MIMEBase', 'MIMEImage', 'MIMEMessage', 'MIMEMu
ltipart', 'MIMENonMultipart', 'MIMEText', 'Message', 'Parser', 'Utils', '_LOWERN
AMES', '_MIMENAMES', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__
', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_name', 'base64MIME', 'email', 'im
porter', 'message_from_file', 'message_from_string', 'mime', 'quopriMIME', 'sys'
]
>>>
```

from the above you can note that MIMEMultipart is readily available to be imported from email.