# Python smtplib error .pyc saved after running

Tags: python

```
import smtplib

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart

from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase

from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

from email import encoders

import os

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\user Account\Desktop\email.py", line 1, in <module>

import smtplib

File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>

import email.utils

File "C:\Users\user Account\Desktop\email.py", line 2, in <module>

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart

ImportError: No module named MIMEMultipart
```

Why is this happening? When I import smtplib via the python sell, I have no issues!

A second copy, .pyc, is saved to the directory of the file and it spits of this error.

Comment: Possible repost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821755/importerror-no-module-named-mime-multipart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name your file `email.py`, this is causing the issue.